# Look for value and sum specific column interval - Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a table with sugar cane replication data and field management
I'd like to search in the red interval for the `FIM SAFRA` value. It may vary in position depending on the time of the year.

Once I find which column contains it, I need to perform a sum in the interval painted in blue, but the sum must stop exactly one column before the `FIM SAFRA` column

I've already tried with `INDEX`, `MATCH` and `VLOOKUP`. Not sure what is the best way. Any Ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
=SUM(V11:INDEX(11:11, 1, MATCH("FIM SAFRA", 10:10, 0)-1))
'to start the rum left of V11,
=SUM(C11:INDEX(11:11, 1, MATCH("FIM SAFRA", 10:10, 0)-1))
```

Comment: Thanks. It looks promissing, but it's only suming the first and the last value before "FIM SAFRA". How can I sum the entire blue interval making this same check. This process will be repated in the next years

Comment: Are you sure here is a `:` colon in `V11:INDEX` and not a `,` comma? You need a `:` colon to make it a range and not two separate cell references.

Comment: OMG! Shame on me! Thanks a lot! It's exactly what I needed